# How to remove/change ubuntu logo in the loging page (Ubuntu 19.04)

Tags: 19.04, login-screen, logo

Example Pic:
[image: example pic]

How can I remove this LOGO (not wallpaper) from the login screen of ubuntu? Is there a specific line I need to change in /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css

Answer (score 7):

the logo is from the package `plymouth`

the file is located at `/usr/share/plymouth/ubuntu-logo.png`

[image]

you can change this Image to your wish or rename it to `ubuntu-logo.png.bak` to hide it..

Comment: Is also valid for 22.04

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**: As of 17-nov-23, removing or renaming *ubuntu-logo.png* will make *initramfs-tools* configuration to fail.

It seems that the install script checks its existence, so maybe it's better to replace it with a transparent png with the same name.